# Why does MySQL stores date in the object of type "TIME"?

Tags: sql, mysql, time, current-time

I've discovered that function `YEAR(CURRENT_TIME())` returns an 2023 year instead of NULL as I thought or something like that.

When i made this query

```
SELECT DAY(CURRENT_TIME()), MONTH(CURRENT_TIME()), YEAR(CURRENT_TIME());
```

I got the next result

```
+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| DAY(CURRENT_TIME()) | MONTH(CURRENT_TIME()) | YEAR(CURRENT_TIME()) |
+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|                  24 |                    11 |                 2023 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

So why does 'TIME' implicitly stores the date?

Comment: the function only returns the string hhMM.ss but "in"  mysql it is a timestamp that i sused to extract the time

Comment: @nbk I'm not sure you are right as timestamps are storef on 4 bytes, while time is stored on 3 bytes

Comment: @Shadow timestamp has all it needs to extract day month and year in it 4 bytes + fractional seconds storage, it gets the datetime from ctime, but as demonstrated the returned string is not the datatype it actually gets

Comment: I see nothing in the documentation that would indicate that the current_time returns timestamp and not time. Considering that there is a curremt_timestamp function, too, it's a bit difficult to explain the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that mysql performs an implicit time -> datetime conversion when you call the year() function on the returned time as year() cannot operate on time data type.

As mysql manual on [date and time data types conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html) says:

> For conversion of TIME values to other temporal types, the value of CURRENT_DATE() is used for the date part.

Comment: dear friend, could you you tell me how I can find the information I need, for example the difference between EXTRACT(YEAR FROM some_date) and YEAR(some_date)?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract - if you have another question, please ask it another question .